# [Netty 4 CR2]Got exception when closing channel by using user-defined encoder and decoder

Tags: netty

I am replacing Netty3 with Netty4 in my project. I am using Google-protocol-buffer as data transfer. I got an exception when closing channel which works fine in Netty3.

Bellowed is the exception details:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(0) + length(4) exceeds writerIndex(0): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 4096)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:95)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:801)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:787)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:808)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$9.run(AbstractChannel.java:725)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:364)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:326)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:114)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(0) + length(4) exceeds writerIndex(0): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 4096)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1120)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readInt(AbstractByteBuf.java:627)
    at com.fhq.mathematica.netty.MMADecoder.decode(MMADecoder.java:17)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeLast(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:168)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:91)
```

Here's the encoder:(Message is the interface of protocol-buffer in top level.)

```
public class MessageEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<Message>{
    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Message msg, ByteBuf out)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] data = msg.toByteArray();
        out.writeInt(data.length);
        out.writeBytes(data);
    }
}
```

Here's the decoder:

```
public class MMADecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder{
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in,
            MessageBuf<Object> out) throws Exception {
        in.markReaderIndex();
        int dataLength = in.readInt();
        if (in.readableBytes() < dataLength) {
            in.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }
        byte[] decoded = new byte[dataLength];
        in.readBytes(decoded);
        out.add(MathematicaTask.parseFrom(decoded));
    }
}
```

When I just transfer MathematicaTask object, it's working fine(both client and server parse message correctly). But when I close the channel there will be an exception in decoder.

```
int dataLength = in.readInt();
```

Could anyone figure out the problem ? Mush appreciated!

BTW : I tried ObjectEncoder and ObjectDecoder, then everything is fine. So there must be some problem in my decoder/encoder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if there are enough bytes to read before call ByteBuf.readInt().

So something like this:

```
public class MMADecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder{
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in,
            MessageBuf<Object> out) throws Exception {
        if (in.readableBytes < 4) {
            return;
        }
        in.markReaderIndex();
        int dataLength = in.readInt();
        if (in.readableBytes() < dataLength) {
            in.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }
        byte[] decoded = new byte[dataLength];
        in.readBytes(decoded);
        out.add(MathematicaTask.parseFrom(decoded));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  it works!  but why we have to compare readable bytes with 4?

Comment: Could you please take look at this question if you have time? Much appraciated.
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394898/how-could-i-display-the-asynchronous-result-in-html-page-through-a-http-request