# How could I display the asynchronous result in HTML page through a HTTP request?

Tags: netty

I am developing an analysis system based on netty version 4, and a web client application based on tomcat.

The web app accepts user's input then send it to analysis machine. Finally prints the response in the HTML page.

This is code in a servlet of sending user's input to analysis node :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
String input = request.getParameter("input");
Channel ch = pool.borrowObject();
Protocol.Builder builder = Protocol.newBuilder().setInput(input);
ch.writeAndFlush(builder.build());
}
```

Netty works asynchronously, so the http request ends after sending.

This is code in response handler:

```
@Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Protocol response)
            throws Exception {
pool.returnObject(ctx.channel());
//How could I code here to display response to the HTML page that user requested?
}
```

I have been struggling here for some weeks. I tried to use a public thead-safe queue to make http request waiting there until got the response from queue. But that made the whole request become synchronous.

Could anyone tell how to do on this ? Many thanks!

Comment: Twitter's Finagle is wrapper for netty that does this (and more).  Most of the examples for writing finagle clients are in scala, but I know it can be used with java too. You can get started here: https://blog.twitter.com/2011/finagle-protocol-agnostic-rpc-system

Comment: @norman-maurer Could you please take a look at this if you have time ? Much appreciated.

Comment: Here is an example of using Finagle to write a Java Server: https://github.com/toulouse/finagle-java-test/blob/master/src/main/java/se/atoulou/www/Main.java I assume the Java Client is simlar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the default servlet request lifecycle is synchronous. The only way you're going to solve this within a servlet container is to make use of servlet 3.0 asynchronous request processing. This way you can pass the request to Netty and return, then write the response asynchronously when it arrives.

Some links to help you get started

[Java Servlet 3.0 Asynchronous Support](http://hmkcode.com/java-servlet-3-0-asynchronous-support/)

[How To Use Asynchronous Servlets To Improve Performance](http://plumbr.eu/blog/how-to-use-asynchronous-servlets-to-improve-performance)